# How to get AKS nodepool vnet in Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

**Existing AKS nodepool information**

Nodepool Virtual network: managed

Nodepool subnet: managed

---

In Bicep script I want to create a private endpoint to connect AKS to Azure Redis service, so I tried to get **vnet name** and **subnetId** of the nodepool.

```
// Get existing k8s cluster
resource cluster 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters@2022-01-02-preview' existing = {
  name: clusterName
}

// Get existing k8s agent pool
resource agentPool 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/agentPools@2022-01-02-preview' existing = {
  parent: cluster
  name: agentPoolName
}

// create private endpoint
resource redisPrivateEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints@2020-07-01' = {
  name: 'redis-pe'
  location: location
  properties: {
    subnet: {
      id: agentPool.properties.vnetSubnetID
    }
    privateLinkServiceConnections: [
      {
        name: 'redis-connection'
        properties: {
          privateLinkServiceId: redis.id
          groupIds: [
            'redisCache'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

There are two problems

1. There is an error message telling me **the value of agentPool.properties.vnetSubnetID doesn't exist**
2. There is no way to get Vnet name using something like, **agentPool.properties.vnet**

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: could you share the bicep file related to AKS creation please ?

Comment: Since I don't see Bicep for the AKS I assume it's been deployed to kubenet instead of Azure Container Networking Interface (CNI) networking hense you don't see it. But as Thomas mentioned it's easier to help if we can see your AKS template.

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve the vnet that is created by AKS. However you can create a VNET prior to AKS and assign nodepools to particular subnets created when you deploy the VNET.

Additionally, you should not create private endpoints in a node pool. create a separate subnet to keep your Private Endpoints. If you plan to use NSGs to restrict which subnets has access to particular PE, it's recommended to create a subnet for each service's PE.